# Postgres ENUM default value, what's recommended? NULL or empty string?

Tags: postgresql, enums

I have a `gender` ENUM field with Male/Female choices.

I wonder what the default value should be. Is it better to use NULL or an empty string?
By default, Postgres (using Xano) picked empty string, but that's counterintuitive to me, I'd rather have gone with a NULL as default.

But, I'm not a Postgres expert and I do not understand what are the consequences of this choice.

Will this choice have consequences if I need to SELECT all users filter by the `gender` field? How?

I feel like both choices are okay, but there might be more to this than I know of.

Comment: You can't store an "empty string" into an enum column. So NULL is your only choice (and it's a sensible choice)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. Xano must come with terrible default values then, good to keep in mind. Or maybe a value isn't needed at all, since the field is not required. Maybe it will store neither NULL nor empty string. I'll see.